# c# IF performance optimization

Tags: c#, .net, performance, if-statement, optimization

Which method is faster for millions of loops ?

double a, b, c, d, e ,f;

1.

```
for (int i=0; i<1000000; i++)
{
  // simulation which changes the a,b,c,d,e,f values
  ...
  if (a>b)
  {
     if (c<d)
     {
       if (e==f)
         // do something
     }
  }
}
```

2.

```
for (int i=0; i<1000000; i++)
{
   // simulation which changes the a,b,c,d,e,f values
   ...
   if ((a>b) && (c<d) && (e==f))
     // do something
}
```

I was thinking that method 1 would be faster because it skips many if comparisons instead of comparing all the 3 variables at once every time.

Comment: https://ericlippert.com/2012/12/17/performance-rant/

Comment: well the idea of millions of loops seems to be not the best approach

Comment: @B001ᛦ why? because this is used in an AI training, there is no other way, but only with hundreds of millions of loops

Comment: Is it a trick question?  They'll both go on for ever with the `while (1)` or until externally terminated.

Comment: @Ian it's not a trick question, it goes for a while not forever, but I have simplified the code

Comment: `while (1)`: how should this compile, 1 is not a bool

Comment: Try `if ((a > b) & (c < d) & (e == f))` since fewer `if` means fewer possibilities for CPU's *branch predictor* to fail when ` & (c < d) & (e == f)` overhead can appear to be little.

Comment: @DmitryBychenko Did you mean `&` rather than `&&`? Because using `&` circumvents the boolean short-circuiting optimisation.

Comment: You should read up on the [`&&`-operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/conditional-and-operator), especially the part about "short-circuit" evaluation

Comment: @Matthew Watson: yes, `(a > b) & (c < d) & (e == f)` will be compiled into computing each term: `(a > b)`, `(c < d)`, `(e == f)` and multiplicating them (`&`) followed by *single* `if`. If terms are *simple* but *random* (which cause branch predictor's failures) avoiding `if`s can be fruitful.

Comment: @musefan it's impossible to do it once! it's used in AI and the if comparison takes a lot of CPU ! everything else is optimized

Comment: @musefan it's not worth to include all the code, because I want to optimize the IFs not the rest of the code, here it takes 60% of the CPU time

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is (probably) a totally unrealistic test, but here you go

## Benchmarks

```
Mode             : Release (64Bit)
Test Framework   : .NET Framework 4.7.1

Operating System : Microsoft Windows 10 Pro
Version          : 10.0.17134

CPU Name         : Intel(R) Core(TM) i7-2600 CPU @ 3.40GHz
Description      : Intel64 Family 6 Model 42 Stepping 7

Cores (Threads)  : 4 (8)      : Architecture  : x64
Clock Speed      : 3401 MHz   : Bus Speed     : 100 MHz
L2Cache          : 1 MB       : L3Cache       : 8 MB

Benchmarks Runs : Inputs (1) * Scales (1) * Benchmarks (3) * Runs (1000) = 3,000
```

**Results**

```
--- Standard input --------------------------------------------------------
| Value  |   Average |   Fastest |     Cycles |  Garbage | Test |    Gain |
--- Scale 1,000,000 --------------------------------------- Time 28.630 ---
| Bit    |  9.120 ms |  8.332 ms | 31,041,747 | 7.477 KB | N/A  | 37.59 % |
| Single | 14.549 ms | 13.815 ms | 49,549,071 | 7.541 KB | N/A  |  0.45 % |
| Multi  | 14.615 ms | 13.806 ms | 49,730,909 | 7.545 KB | Base |  0.00 % |
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

**Test Data**

```
private List<Tuple<double, double, double, double, double, double>> GenerateInput(int scale)
{
   var list = Enumerable.Range(0, scale)
                        .Select(x => new Tuple<double, double, double, double, double, double>(Rand.Next(), Rand.Next(), Rand.Next(), Rand.Next(), Rand.Next(), Rand.Next()))
                        .ToList();
   return list;
}
```

**Multi**

```
public class Multi : Benchmark<List<Tuple<double, double, double, double, double, double>>, int>
{
   protected override int InternalRun()
   {
      int i = 0;
      foreach (var item in Input)
         if (item.Item1 > item.Item2)
            if (item.Item3 < item.Item4)
               if (item.Item5 == item.Item6)
                  i++;

      return i;
   }    
}
```

**Single**

```
public class Single : Benchmark<List<Tuple<double, double, double, double, double, double>>, int>
{
   protected override int InternalRun()
   {
      int i = 0;
      foreach (var item in Input)
         if ((item.Item1 > item.Item2) && (item.Item3 < item.Item4) && (item.Item5 == item.Item6))
            i++;

      return i;
   }
}
```

**Bit**

```
public class Bit : Benchmark<List<Tuple<double, double, double, double, double, double>>, int>
{
   protected override int InternalRun()
   {
      int i = 0;
      foreach (var item in Input)
         if ((item.Item1 > item.Item2) & (item.Item3 < item.Item4) & (item.Item5 == item.Item6))
            i++;

      return i;
   } 
}
```

Comment: Thank you! so it seems the Bit is much faster, also it skips more comparisons

Comment: @MarioM yeah i just run a bunch more comparisons, single and multi are pretty interchangeable in the results, bit is always about 35% faster on my cpu

Comment: 35% is a lot for my project! it takes hours to complete the simulation and the IFs are taking most of the CPU also there are 6 of them, but I made the question more simple with 3

Answer (score 2):

You're incorrect. C#'s [`&&` operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/conditional-and-operator) uses something called [short-circuit evaluation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation).

Plainly, when evaluating `a && b`, if `a` is `false`, the computer won't bother with evaluating `b`.

Both snippets should perform identically.

Comment: It's not entirely clear why this got downvotes. So maybe someone can explain it

Comment: `"Both snippets should perform identically."` Yeah... they will both give you a compilation error. I disagree with you providing an answer to such a poor question by the way

Comment: Short-circuiting does not depend on the language, it depends on the operator.  Using & is just fine here.  And is likely to produce faster code since on a modern core these comparisons run concurrently.  Haswell for example can run 4 integer comparisons at the same time and (I think) 2 floating point comparisons.  No point in trying to bypass a comparison that takes a fraction of a cpu cycle, the branch only adds to the cost.  Using == on doubles is however always wrong.  Hard to give good answers to bad code.

Comment: @HansPassant: But this answer isn't wrong or bad anyway because it just says that both approaches basically do the same thanks to the `&&` operator

Comment: @TimSchmelter Some people tend to down-vote any short answer regardless of its content! I see nothing wrong with the answer too.

Comment: Erm, I didn't vote for this post.  Just saw a minor technical incorrectness, that's all.  I'd vote it up if it talked about why it is sometimes a good idea to *avoid* short-circuiting.